# Laravel Ordering on Piviot table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
    public function get_user_documents()
    {
        $userId = Auth::id();
        $user_documents = UserDocument::where('user_id', $userId)
            ->orWhereHas('share_documents', function ($query) use ($userId) {
                $query->where('users.id', $userId);
            })
            ->with(['share_documents' => function ($query) use ($userId) {
                $query->where('users.id', $userId);
            }])
            ->latest()
            ->get();

        // $user_documents = $user_documents->map(function ($document) use ($userId) {
        //     $status = $document->user_id == $userId ? 'owned' : 'shared';
        //     $document->status = $status;
        //     return $document;
        // });
        return response()->json($user_documents);
    }
```

Can we ordering on both Base table and Piviot table
i want to get latest record on top it is owned document or shared document

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function get_user_documents()
{
    $userId = Auth::id();
    $user_documents = UserDocument::where('user_id', $userId)
        ->orWhereHas('share_documents', function ($query) use ($userId) {
            $query->where('users.id', $userId);
        })
        ->with(['share_documents' => function ($query) use ($userId) {
            $query->latest()->where('users.id', $userId);
        }])
        ->latest()
        ->get();

    // $user_documents = $user_documents->map(function ($document) use ($userId) {
    //     $status = $document->user_id == $userId ? 'owned' : 'shared';
    //     $document->status = $status;
    //     return $document;
    // });
    return response()->json($user_documents);
}
```